# Modify a text file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, dsquery

I have the following in myFile.txt:

`samid
  xxuserMike
  xxuserDave
  xxuserSue
dsget succeeded`

I'd like to use a batch commands to make it:

`"xxuserMike"
"xxuserDave"
"xxuserSue"`

Side note, the original file is created using dsquery / dsget to make a list of users from a specific group in AD.  If there is a way to format that output from the start, all the better.  The command I'm using is:
`dsquery group -name "myADgroup" | dsget group -members | dsget user -samid > myFile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "skip=1" %%a in (
  'dsquery group -name "myADGroup"^| dsget group -members^| dsget user -samid'
  ) do ( 
    set l="%%a"
    echo(!l:"dsget"=!
))>myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's close but it's putting:
( "xxuserMike"
( "xxuserDave"
etc.
would you mind helping me remove the "( " as well?

Comment: ok, I removed the last ( in the code you provided and everything looks good, it just says "Echo is off." at the end of the file.  If I can just suppress that I'll be golden.  Thanks

Comment: `echo(!l:"dsget"=!` <--- try it as posted.  You must have put a space after the `echo`

Comment: Thanks foxidrive, that was it.